# Conditionally replacing NaNs Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nan

sorry for the n00b question.

I'm new to Kaggle and have begun looking at some of their competitions, and one of their beginner ones is on the famous Titanic data. My question regards filling NaNs in for the Age column. What I would like to do is for each NaN in the Age column I'd like to replace it with the average age for that Class and Sex.

For example, passengerID 6 is a Man from 3rd class, and he has a NaN age. What I'd like is to replace that NaN with the average age of 3rd class males. Which is 26.5.

What I've tried so far is the following:

```
man_1 = train[(train['male'] == 1) & (train['Pclass'] == 1)]['Age'].mean()
train[(train['male'] == 1) & (train['Pclass'] == 1)]['Age'].fillna(man_1, inplace=True)

man_2 = train[(train['male'] == 1) & (train['Pclass'] == 2)]['Age'].mean()
train[(train['male'] == 1) & (train['Pclass'] == 2)]['Age'].fillna(man_2, inplace=True)

man_3 = train[(train['male'] == 1) & (train['Pclass'] == 3)]['Age'].mean()
train[(train['male'] == 1) & (train['Pclass'] == 3)]['Age'].fillna(man_3, inplace=True)

wom_1 = train[(train['male'] == 0) & (train['Pclass'] == 1)]['Age'].mean()
train[(train['male'] == 0) & (train['Pclass'] == 1)]['Age'].fillna(wom_1, inplace=True)

wom_2 = train[(train['male'] == 0) & (train['Pclass'] == 2)]['Age'].mean()
train[(train['male'] == 0) & (train['Pclass'] == 2)]['Age'].fillna(wom_2, inplace=True)

wom_3 = train[(train['male'] == 0) & (train['Pclass'] == 3)]['Age'].mean()
train[(train['male'] == 0) & (train['Pclass'] == 3)]['Age'].fillna(wom_3, inplace=True)
```

And quelle suprise it doens't work. I'm not sure why though? Firstly if anyone could suggest why it doesn't work that would be great. Secondly, I feel like there should be a more 'Pythonistic' way of doing this, but I'm not sure how exactly. I'm aware there is another possibly duplicate topic on Stack but it doesn't quite explain why my code isn't working, so sorry if this post annoys people. Cheers

Comment: 'Pythonistic'  >> **pythonic** ;)

Comment: what if you use '.loc' ? 

`train.loc[(train['male'] == 1) & (train['Pclass'] == 1),'Age'].fillna(man_1, inplace=True)`

Comment: The NaNs are still there :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one pass with `groupby().transform()`

```
s = train.groupby(['male', 'Pclass'])['Age'].transform('mean')

df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(s)
```

Comment: I usually prefer explicit assignment over `inplace` for readability and debugging.